# Error on wrong Input Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java

There is a problem if I put `int number = scanner.nextInt ();` in the `if` bracket and write a wrong input it works well.

But if I do not write it outside of `if`, it gives the following error when I type a wrong input

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at UserInput.main(UserInput.java:15)
```

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInput {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Sum=0, counter = 0,no=1;
    Scanner scanner;
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter number #" + no + " = ");

        boolean result =  scanner.hasNextInt();
        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        if(result == true)
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
            Sum = Sum + number;
            no = no+1;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        scanner.nextLine();
        }while(counter<10);
    System.out.println("Sum = " + Sum );
    scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not describe your input like *wrong input*. Just tell what it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hasNextInt() returns false, that means that the scanners next token (token=fragment of the object that is "scanned") is not an Integer. If you now invoke the Method nextInt() although the next token is in fact not an Integer, then you get the InputMismatchException. As Scott said, by putting the call within the if-statement you can prevent this from happening because you make sure, that the next token is an Integer and you can actually call nextInt().

Answer (score 0):

By putting it in the `if`, you don't call `nextInt` unless you know there is one to get (i.e. `result` is true).

Comment: You are saying that if the hasnextInt() is false and i call nextInt() it gives error?

Comment: If `hasNextInt()` returns false, there shouldn't be an `int` to get.